# Windows SBS 2011 DNS Role (service) failing & needing restarting

Tags: exchange, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server, exchange-2010, windows-sbs

Have a Windows SBS 2011 with Exchange that is handling all DNS for the network.

Since getting a 3rd party (Hardware & Support) to setup a recieving FTP service and [restricting Exchanges memory useage](http://eightwone.com/2011/04/06/limiting-exchange-2010-sp1-database-cache/) for another 3rd party product (Stock software) the local network seems to periodically 'lose the internet connection'.

Delving deeper I found that the DNS service is somehow failing/stopping without the actual service on the server reporting such (nothing in event logs). A simple restart of the 'DNS Role' on the server solves the problem.

The manager onsite reports that he has to do this most days in the afternoon - yet not at the same time and other days it works fine without a restart being required.

I'm unable (lacking sufficient SBS2011 knowledge) to diagnose this further, ideally I would like the DNS Role to report (and log) the failure, then automatically restart itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking deeper - auto-updates had been disabled on the server ('so the Administrator can review and install them as and when required').

I have a feeling one of these updates will probably fix the issue, but until I get time to go onsite and install them (we may escalate the support contract to cover updates), a script has been written  to restart the DNS service and scheduled it to run daily.

Not really a concise answer, more of a 'fix'. :)